# How do I perform an intersect of a selection and a union effectively?

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a code that will fill the users selection with a colour so long as that selection is completely incompassed within a union of ranges.

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Selection, Union(Range("B4:X23"), Range("Z4:AH23"), _
                              Range("B25:X32"), Range("Z25:AH32"),Range("B34:X44"),  _
                              Range("Z34:AH44"))) Is Nothing Then   
    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = modButtons.intColour   
End If
```

Performing this line several times for individual ranges isn't an option because There is 30 range sets in my actual code.

So the issue is that while it won't fill in cells in the selection when the active cell is outside the ranges, it will fill cells in the selection that are outside the ranges if the active cell is inside the range.

Comment: If the selection is fully contained within your unioned ranges then the intersect and the selection will both have the same number of cells...

Comment: @Sam Could you explain in a bit more detailed form why "Performing this line several times for individual ranges isn't an option". Is it because you do not like typin much or is there a more technical reason?

Comment: That is a good point Tim.

Comment: @Gene No I just thought that performing the same if statement thirty times wasn't very elegant

Comment: @Sam  I agree, it is not... But it seems you have to type the ranges in no matter what. You could type them (the addresses) into a comma-delimited string (string constant). Then set up a for loop with the Split(strRangeAddresses,",") array.... Anyways, it seems you are quite OK with the silentsurfer's solution., so this does not matter. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

If in case of partial overlaps you want to fill only the intersected range of your selection, use:

```
Dim rngIntersect As Range 
Set rngIntersect = Intersect(Selection, Union(Range("B4:X23"), Range("Z4:AH23"), _
                              Range("B25:X32"), Range("Z25:AH32"), Range("B34:X44"), _
                              Range("Z34:AH44")))

If Not rngIntersect Is Nothing Then
    rngIntersect.Interior.ColorIndex = modButtons.intColour 
End If
```

If you want to fill your selection only if it is completely intersected, use:

```
Dim rngIntersect As Range 
Set rngIntersect = Intersect(Selection, Union(Range("B4:X23"), Range("Z4:AH23"), _
                              Range("B25:X32"), Range("Z25:AH32"), Range("B34:X44"), _
                              Range("Z34:AH44")))

If Not rngIntersect Is Nothing And rngIntersect.Cells.Count = Selection.Cells.Count Then
    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = modButtons.intColour 
End If
```

Comment: This is **Perfect**. I was planning on using the second solution you've posted but the user found that the first solution was much easier to understand.